# How to inflate a new view, inside a custom view, programmatically (Android)

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I created a custom view where I inflate a new View:

```
<declare-styleable name="my_view">
    <attr format="reference" name="my_layout"/>
</declare-styleable>


public class MyCustomView extends FrameLayout {
     [...]

    private void initialize(AttributeSet attrs) {

    int myLayout = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.my_layout, -1);

    attrs.recycle();
    inflate(this.getContext(), myLayout, this);

    [...]
}
```

And I call this way, on XML file:

```
view:my_layout="@layout/custom_layout"
```

It works fine!

But what I want, is set this custom_layout programmatically, so I can put in an if clause, to choose between two different layouts.

I tried create a public methos inside this custom class:

```
private myCustomLayout = -1;

public void setCustomLayout(int id)
{
    this.myCustomLayout = id;
}
```

then, I changed this:

```
int myLayout = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.my_layout, -1);
```

to this:

```
int myLayout = myCustomLayout;
```

But obviously it didn't work.

Does anyone knows, how can I do this?

Comment: When do you want to make the decision? At the time of view creation or at any given time?

Comment: I want to make this decision on the method OnCreate() of my activity classe...  I want to make the same as when I set a Text on a textView, like myText.seText("text"); but with my view... Something like myCustomView.setLayout(R.layout.myLayout);

Comment: I think I need to create a public method, inside my custom view classe, so I can access and send my specific layout... But I don't know how inflate this sent view, inside the initialize() method (inside custom view class)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `initialize()` will be called from your custom view's constructors. So it would not be wise to inflate the view in it. You can remove the code to inflate view from it.

Add following method in you `CustomView`:

```
public void setCustomLayout(int layout) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    inflater.inflate(layout, this);
    invalidate();
}
```

If your layout contains layout params then it will be fine, if not then you may need add layout params while inflating the layout.

Call the above method from your `onCreate()` with appropriate view.